# Cannot apply CSS properties to navbar elements

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap demo where I have built a navbar but can't seem to target its components for CSS purposes.

DEMO: https://www.bootply.com/HeDASKTqwt

I would like to target all menu links and change their font color. In CSS I have commented out the font size property which upon applying would change the font for all links. This should suggest that targeting of these specific HTML attributes (
.navbar-default li) is correct but somehow the color property doesn't apply. I have analyzed this behavior in Chrome Devtools and the font color property is striked through. I could change the font color by applying !important but I tend to run into same problem all over again and overuse this property with Bootstrap framework which is obviously not a good practice. I have tried different ways to target navbar elements but so far I had peculiar and non-consistent results. I can't seem to understand this targeting behavior of BS.

I also have a problem with Login link. If I change the font size of all menu links the login link gets misplaced in a navbar row. I have applied margin-top property in HTML to Login link but I would like to avoid manually adjusting this its value to fit the selected font size. Is there a better way how to get all the links aligned for different font sizes and screen resolutions?

Comment: What font size would you like for your menu links & login link? I'll add this to my answer once I know.

Comment: @ProEvilz I am not sure yet, but I would definitely want to increase the font size.

Comment: Well this kind of an integral part to helping you... if you don't know how big you want it then I can't really help much. You should also post a screenshot of what it looks like when your login link is misplaced. I suspect this also ties into the size of your screen...

Comment: @ProEvilz You could see the login link being misplaced if you would change CSS font-size property in demo (its originally commented out). For the desired font-size: I think 20px would look fine.

Comment: Bootply seems to be down for me at the moment.

Comment: @ProEvilz Looks like I cannot access BP either.

Comment: @ProEvilz Alright, the BP is working again. Could you take a look at login misplacement problem? Also I targeted navbar menu links like you suggested in a comment below but somehow the change doesn't apply in my actual project (I made sure there are no other color properties applied in my CSS). Only forcing !important on the color property helps. I am getting frustrated with BS logic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152746/discussion-between-proevilz-and-no-this-is-patrick).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To target the links and change the color, you need to target the `<a>` tags that reside *within* the `<li>` tags like so:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a {
  color:red;
}
```

The reason targeting the `<li>` tags alone doesn't work is because the `<a>` tags inside have a default color applied to it. Further more, the text is wrapped within the `<a> </a>` tags and not the `<li> </li>` it's self as seen in the inspector.

[image]

Comment: Could you explain why targeting ".navbar-default .navbar-nav" works but targeting ".navbar-nav" alone doesn't?

Comment: Well, I assume you mean in regards to changing text color? targeting `.navbar-nav` alone isn't where the text is precisely. See the image above, you'll see that there is a `<li>` tag and then an `<a>` tag. Generally, you want to select the closest tag to your element you wish to style.

Comment: So technically I should be very precise with all the parent and child elements if I want to target specific element? I thought that just targeting the parent would suffice but I guess being as precise as possible is a BS specific rule.

Comment: Correct. Targeting the parent isn't enough in BS because BS applies specific styles to those child elements by default. As seen in the image, there is a default color and background color applied by bootstrap. We must target them specifically to override that.

Comment: You don't need to be overly precise though. The main important part is that you have to make sure your target ends with the specific element you want. E.g. you don't have to start with `body` and select all elements all the way down to the <a> tags.